# How to make a responsive isotope gallery plugin in different screen size?

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-isotope

[image]I want to make the following isotope gallery responsive for all different screen size. there is always a gap whenever I want to see it in the smaller size window (320px,576px,768px). How can I solve it?

My website link:[Website](https://amuntaseer91.github.io/Vacation/)

Thank You.

```js
$('.i_gallery').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.g_item',
    percentPosition: true,
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: '.g_item'
    }
});

//filtering Click function

$('.portfolio-menu ul li').click(function() {
    $('.portfolio-menu ul li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');

    let filterItems = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $('.i_gallery').isotope({
        filter: filterItems
    })
    return false;
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">

        <div class="portfolio-menu">
            <ul>
                <li class="active">All</li>
                <li data-filter=".web">Web Design</li>
                <li data-filter=".logo">Logo Design</li>
                <li data-filter=".wordpress">WordPress</li>
                <li data-filter=".ecommerce">E-Commerce</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="i_gallery">
            <div class="g_item web">
                <img src="image/10.png" alt="" class="img-fluid">
            </div>
            <div class="g_item web">
                <img src="image/11.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="g_item wordpress">
                <img src="image/12.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="g_item wordpress">
                <img src="image/13.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="g_item logo">
                <img src="image/14.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="g_item logo">
                <img src="image/15.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="g_item ecommerce">
                <img src="image/16.png" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="g_item ecommerce">
                <img src="image/17.png" alt="">
            </div>


        </div>
    </div>
```

I have attached the external Js file and HTML file of the isotope gallery.

Comment: Share the code, you have already created

Comment: I could probably right a solution for you using media queries, but I don't fully understand the end result that you are looking for. Now days responsive designs are generally achieved using CSS media queries, rather than with a JS framework like JQuery.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Actually, I want to show the responsive isotope gallery for all screen size in media query. I have attached one image where there is a white gap in the tablet size screen, and I want to fix that. @Aft3rL1f3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isotope gallery seems to be occupying 94% all the time. You can try giving 3% margin to the parent container. So the gallery

```css
i_gallery {
  width: 100%;
  /* margin: 0 auto; */
  margin: 3%;
}
```

will come at center.

Comment: Thank you, the solutions worked @vishnu sandhireddy